# SharePoint Workflow Development in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise

For the development in SharePoint 2008, I been installed Visual Studio 2008 extensions  for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 v1.3.

It is successfully installed, but when I create a new project in Visual Studio 2008, how come the SharePoint Project types only got 5 templates (Team Site Definition, Blank Site Definition, List Definition, Web Part and Empty)?

My questions is I wanted to develop a workflow project in SharePoint, which template should I choose?

If I choose Empty Template and add item (Sequential Workflow (code)) from Workflow categories, the project hit error on References (System.Workflow.ComponentModel). It happen the same for using WSPBuilder project.

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 v1.3 not provides templates for WF, it's done by tools for WF or Office please see the article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/sharepointworkflow.aspx and these tools installed by default. Please check this nodes in available Projects.